# html code inserted javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a javascript function, and I've put in the html code javascipt, but when I make a branching using if else there is an error with the statement "SyntaxError: missing) after argument list" on the sidelines "if" is. following my javascript code.

```
function tabelListPegawai(data){
    return baris = $('<tr>\
            <td>'+data.nik+'</td>\
            <td>'+data.nama_pegawai+'</td>\
            <td>'+data.nama+'</td>\
            <td>'+data.nama_jabatan+'</td>\
            <td>'if(data.status == 1){'Karyawan Tetap'}else if(data.status == 2){'Karyawan Tidak Tetap'}'</td>\
            <td style="text-align: center;">\
            <a class="btn btn-small aksi_atas" rel="tooltip" title="Ubah" onclick="editPegawai('+data.id_pegawai+')"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>\
            <a class="btn btn-small aksi_atas" rel="tooltip" title="Hapus" onclick="hapusPegawai('+data.id_pegawai+', '+data.nik+')"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>\
            </td>\
    </tr>'); 
}
```

Can you help me. thank you

Comment: You can't interpolate `if..else` like that but you can use a ternary operator. Also I'd recommend concatenating your string properly with `+` for best support across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the switch is only 1 or 2 then this would work

```
 <td>' + (data.status == 1?  'Karyawan Tetap' : 'Karyawan Tidak Tetap') + '</td>\
```

Or you could do this

```
 var baris = $('<tr>\
  ...
 <td>';
 if(data.status == 1) baris+='Karyawan Tetap';
 else if(data.status == 2) baris+='Karyawan Tidak Tetap';
 baris+=' <td style="text-align: center;">\
 ....
```